# Colorbox: Controlling order within rel group (gallery)

Tags: gallery, grouping, colorbox

In ColorBox, is it possible to control the order that photos appear within a grouped (rel="group") gallery?

Unfortunately, due to the layout of my page, photos appear in vertical columns, which need to be grouped horizontally. So the links are output in vertical order in the html, ie:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

...but need to be displayed as...

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

What I need to be able to do, is to override the natural order, sort of like a tabindex, ie:

```
rel="group[1]"
rel="group[4]"
rel="group[7]"

rel="group[2]"
rel="group[5]"
rel="group[8]"

rel="group[3]"
rel="group[6]"
rel="group[9]"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I can't think of any easy way to do this.  Colorbox's ordering is controlled by DOM placement and there isn't a way to alter that outside of editing the plugin.  The easiest thing to do would be somewhat ugly: create a duplicate set of DOM elements in the correct order and assign colorbox to them instead (this could be done with JS and they could have their display set to none so they are hidden from the visitor).  Then use the original links to trigger colorbox on the duplicate link that shares the same href value.

Comment: Thanks Jack, that is a good work around. However, I have decided to alter my layout so that elements appear in the dom in the correct order, and use jQuery to rearrange them afterwards. This seems to solve my problem!